# My Tester Class in Incomplete and I'm trying to decide if I need to pull methods from my other classes

Tags: java, testing, methods, arraylist, compile-time

I am having problems deciding which methods I should pull out of my VendingMachine Class and placed in my TesterClass to test my program.  I am attempting to test the VendingMachine and the Candy Classes by constructing Candy objects in my ArrayList but I'm not sure how to best accomplish this.  The ArrayList of Candy objects contain the candy bar string and a double price.  I want my tester to run the vending machine methods that prompt the user for the questions that are listed in the println methods.

Tester Class

```
    public class Tester {
        private static Object candyBarList;

        public static void main(String args[])
    { 
             WHAT METHODS SHOULD I PLACE HERE
    }
```

Candy Class

```
    public class Candy{
    private double price;
    private String candyBarName;    

    Candy()
    {
    price = 1.50;
    candyBarName = "Pluto Bar";
    //default constructor
    }
    Candy(double price1, String str){
    price = price1;
    candyBarName = str;
    //constructor with parameters
    }
    public double getPrice(){
    return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price){
    this.price = price;
    }
    public String getCandyBarName(){
    return candyBarName;
    }
    public void setCandyBarName(String candyBarName){
    this.candyBarName = candyBarName;
    }
```

Vending Machine Class

```
    }

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import vendingmachine.Candy;
    package vendingmachine;

    /**
    *
    * @author admin
    */
    public class VendingMachine {

    double money = 0.0;
    Candy candyBar = new Candy();
    ArrayList<Candy> candyBarList = new ArrayList<>();
    double cashBox = 0.0;

    public VendingMachine(){

    candyBarList.add(candyBar);
    candyBarList.add(new Candy(2.00, "Snickers Bar"));
    candyBarList.add(new Candy(2.00, "Snickers Bar")); 
    candyBarList.add(new Candy(2.00, "Snickers Bar")); 
    candyBarList.add(new Candy(2.00, "Snickers Bar")); 
    candyBarList.add(new Candy(2.00, "Snickers Bar"));     
    }

    /**
    * @return 
    */ 

    public double paymentIn(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //double payAmount=0.0;

    System.out.println("Insert Money: ");
    double payAmount = input.nextDouble();

    return payAmount;
    }

    public static boolean isPaymentEnough(double depositMoney, double price){

    if (depositMoney >= price)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

    }

    public  void dispenseCandy (double depositMoney, Candy selectedCandy){
        cashBox+= depositMoney - selectedCandy.getPrice();
        candyBarList.remove(selectedCandy);                     

    }

    public String candySelector(){    
        for (int i=0; candyBarList.size() >= i; i++){

        System.out.println(candyBarList.get(i));

    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String candyBarSelected = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please type in the Candy Bar you would like");
    candyBarSelected = input.next();

    return candyBarSelected;

    }

    public Candy findCandy(){
    String candyName = candySelector();

    for (int i=0; candyBarList.size() >= i; i++){

        if (candyBarList.get(i).getCandyBarName().equals(candyName)){
        return candyBarList.get(i);
        }           

    }
    System.out.println("Your selection is invalid");
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your `Tester` class obtains an instance of `VendingMachine` that gives it access to all public methods of the class. Why do you feel a need to *duplicate* anything?

Comment: I am not sure I need to duplicate it per se.  I was wondering if I could pull those methods out of the vending machine class and place them in the tester.